# Dialogflow webdemo iframe blocked

Tags: iframe, cross-domain, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I'm working on a chatbot with Dialogflow and I'm really impressed of all its functionality. I set up an fully working agent and want to use it on my website. But the cross-origin iframe gets blocked.

Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://console.dialogflow.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

What do I miss, as this is the official method to publish my bot on my page?

I use the following example code

```
<iframe
    allow="microphone;"
    width="350"
    height="430"
    src="https://console.dialogflow.com/api-client/demo/embedded/c3f5abdb-c28d-4244-acc7-53abc91f0e8e">
</iframe>
```

It displays the agent but I cannot activate or use it...

Comment: Can you post the code for your page?

Comment: I edited the question. All code is from the original webpage. This is the code snippet for the web-demo

Comment: I've tested this iframe code and it works for me - you can easily confirm this yourself by opening the web inspector and inserting it to the HTML for any web page (you can even try it on this StackOverflow post). Could there be something in your server configuration or HTML that is preventing cross-origin requests from your page?